# Number of ways $10$ men and $4$ women can sit at a round table so there is no block of $3$ consecutive women

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> In how many ways can $10$ men and $4$ women sit at a round table so that there is no block of $3$ consecutive women?

Since there is no restriction on men, I thought they should sit first. Since the table is round, I fixed one seat for $1$ in 10 men and placed the rest of them $9!$ ways and then we have $10$ gaps in which we can place $4$ women, at most $2$ in each. I think these are the possibilities:

1. One woman in each gap: we can choose those gaps in $\binom{10}4$ ways and then place women in $4!$ different ways.
2. $2$ women in  $1$ gap and the remaining $2$ in each of their own. We need $3$ gaps altogether, which can be chosen in $\binom{10}3$ ways. Since women are different entities, I believe we should be able to place them in, again $4!$ ways.
3. $2$ women in $2$ gaps: $2$ in each. We can choose $2$ gaps in $\binom{10}2$ ways and again, if I'm not wrong, place them in $4!$ ways.

Therefore, my answer to the number of possible ways is: $$9!\cdot 4!\left(\binom{10}4+\binom{10}3+\binom{10}2\right).$$

Can somebody check my answer as I'm not quite sure im my deduction?

Comment: I assume 14 chairs ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, sure, let it be as chairs are not mentioned.

Comment: I believe you are overcounting several seatings

Comment: I've noticed I wrote $10!$ instead of $9!$, what I thought I should've written in the end.

Comment: I mean that your method of using gaps is inherently overcounting when the people are distinguishable.

Comment: It might be easier to count the possibilities of 3 women in a row and then find the complement.

Or at least use that as doube check on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is missing factor of $3$ in the second term.

$ \displaystyle 9!\cdot 4!\left(\binom{10}4+ \color {blue} {3} \cdot \binom{10}3+\binom{10}2\right)$

Why $3$? That's because when you make groups of $2, 1$ and $1$ women and choose $3$ spaces between men to seat them which is ${10 \choose 3}$, you also have $3$ ways to choose which of those $3$ spaces will have two women.

Alternatively, subtract arrangements which have $3$ or $4$ consecutive women from total arrangements of $13!$. So the answer can also be written as,

$ \displaystyle 13! - (10! \cdot 9 + 10!) \cdot 4!$

Explanation:

First term being subtracted - three consecutive women. Let's first seat three women together and then men can be arranged in $10!$ ways. The lone woman can sit in $9$ spaces between men. Finally women can be arranged within in $4!$ ways.

Second term being subtracted - all four women sit together. Let's first seat all women together and then men can be arranged in $10!$ ways. Finally women can be arranged within in $4!$ ways.

Comment: You seem to have edited your work. You initially had $\displaystyle 9!\cdot 4!\left(\binom{10}4+  \binom{10}3+\binom{10}2\right)$. I corrected it to $\displaystyle 9!\cdot 4!\left(\binom{10}4+ \color {blue} {3} \cdot \binom{10}3+\binom{10}2\right)$. That should give the correct answer.

Comment: First term is where all $4$ women sit separately. So we choose $4$ spots and $4!$ counts all arrangements. Similarly the last term is where we choose $2$ spots between men and seat two women in each spot. Again $4!$ counts all arrangements. It is only in the second term that we choose $3$ spots with two women in one spot and a woman each in other two spots. Now two women could be in any of the $3$ chosen spots and then other two spots will automatically have a woman each. So we multiply by $3 \cdot 4!$ to count all arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the seats are numbered $1$ to $14$. Fix an arbitrary man at seat $1$. Now we have $9$ men left and $4$ women left to seat.

Now consider the remaining $13$ seats. Since the man in seat $1$ is blocking any possibility of a consecutive block of women wrapping around, we just need to find the number of ways to put the remaining $13$ people in a line so that we don't have a consecutive block of $3$ women.

We will use complimentary counting. There are of course $13!$ ways to seat the $13$ people with no attention to restrictions. The only way to have a consecutive block of $3$ women is if there is a block of exactly $3$ women or a block of exactly $4$ women.

For the first case, there are $\binom{4}{3}\cdot 3!$ ways to choose the $3$ women in the block and then order them. There are $11!$ ways to arrange the $9+2=11$ entities. However, $10\cdot 2\cdot 9!$ of these have a block of $4$ women. So there are a total of $216\cdot 10!$ ways to arrange this case.

For the second case, there are $4!$ ways to arrange the $4$ women in the block. There are $10!$ ways to arrange the $10$ entities. Hence the total is $24\cdot 10!$

So the total is $13!-240\cdot 10!=\boxed{1476\cdot 10!}$.

Comment: So, you counted, for the first case, a block of $3$ women as $1$ entity, and that, with the remaining woman and $9$ remaining men gives $11$ entities?

Comment: @dolphin Yes that is correct